# Remove product from recently viewed

Tags: magento-1.7, product-list

I want to show on recently viewed products list button for removing product from that list. Is the way to do it?

Some more details:

1. There is available with Magento, out of the box, block with recently viewed products, where we can see all products, which we have visited on the shop.
2. I want to show REMOVE button near each of product on recently viewed list.
3. When I click REMOVE button, I want to product related to this button disappear from recently viewed products list.

Comment: Michal can you please describe more details...

Comment: @AmitBera: I've edited first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Recently viewed products data are stored in this table **report_viewed_product_index.**

you can delete records based on customer_id/visitor_id.